# osm2po v5.1.0 concave shapes

Tags: osm2po

According to release notes version 5.1.0 is capable of generating concave shapes. However, I cannot find any information on how to use this new feature.

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, quite undocumented - albeit asked the first time.

Using Java this can be done via

```
public ConcaveHull(Graph graph, Log log) ...
public int[] build(int[] vids, float alpha) ...
```

where `vids` are the vertexIds to visualize as hull and `alpha` the shape accuracy.

Using the REST-Service the same can be achieved by using the `hullAlpha` parameter in addition to the `cmd=fh`.

The `hullAlpha` is just a threshold value in degrees, preventing the algo from diving too deep. Depending on the area, start with e.g. 1 and decrease it as you like. But be cautious, the chosen value has strong impact on performance and memory usage.

[image: osm2po concave hull]